# Create .mobileprovision file offline

Tags: code-signing, provisioning-profile, enterprise

Is it possible to create a `.mobileprovision` file without using the developer portal? I need this as part of an offline signature tool for enterprise applications.

Regards
Maciej

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i see that they are actually signed by "Apple iPhone OS Provisioning Profile Signing" so there is no way to do what i wanted. Unless someone feels like sharing the private key for that certificate ;)